# Laravel response make csv via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, csv

Hi I'm using Laravels response class to generate a csv as follows;

```
$output = 'id,username,email'. "\n";

foreach ($users as $user) {
          $output .= implode(",", [
                          $user->id,
                          $user->username,
                          $user->email,   
                ]) . "\n";
}

$headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="users.csv"',
        ];
    return \Response::make($output, 200, $headers);
```

This works if I submit the form as per normal. However I want to do this download via ajax, if I do this via ajax as follows;

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#export', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myForm = $(this);
    data = $(this).serialize();

    //var
    $.ajax({
        url: myForm.attr('action'),
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: data,
        type: myForm.attr('method'),
        success: function (json) {
            console.log(json);
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, json, errorThrown) {
            alert('An unexpected error occured, please try again or contact.');
        }

    });
});
```

Now this is successful however the file doesn't download, instead the response via ajax is as follows;

```
id,username,email,1,user1,user@email.com,2,user2,user2@email.com
```

Any ideas how I can force this file to download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another route

1.In the controller function for that route you return the url for the route that you currently ajaxing to it

2.Change the ajax function to get this new route

3.when the ajax is triggered it takes the url of the csv
in the ajax success function you trigger the csv download using ether `window.location` or by click triggering a hidden link with a download attribute